# Freezing the header of composite report in PowerBuilder 6.5

Tags: powerbuilder

**Setup**:

Using PowerBuilder 6.5.

I have a composite report (with a report header) which is created from two unrelated individual DataWindows.

**Question**:

In composite presentation style, how can I freeze (lock) composite report header along with the column headers in the **top** DataWindow?

E.g. When you scroll down the composite report, both of the headers should remain visible.

Thanks!

Comment: P.S. Google didn't seem to help - may be i'm googling for the wrong terms :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composite reports are always presented in print preview mode, showing the report as an image of what is displayed on the page. You won't get frozen headers with this. Sorry.

Good luck,

Terry.